# Namespace rails belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following configuration

```
module Account
   class Permission <ApplicationRecord
   end
end

module Account
   class GroupPermission < ApplicationRecord
     belongs_to: permission
   end
end

Table: account_permissions
          name character varying,
             
Table: account_group_permissions
        account_permissions_id bigint,
       account_groups_id bigint,
```

When I try to access the Account :: GroupPermission instance and through it access Account :: Permission returns nil.

Only works if I specify class_name:

Comment: is account  model?

Comment: I don't have a model account

Comment: Your code is inconsistent. You've written classes called `Permission` and `GroupPermissions`, yet directly below you say the tables are *`account_group_users`* and `account_group_permissons`. Did you supply the wrong information above, or is there an issue with database?

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#controlling-association-scope), this should work fine without specifying the `class_name`. Is there anything else important that you may need to mention? E.g. You're using an old version of rails, or an 'unusual' gem, or have added some other 'unusual' code?

Comment: Tables ajusted, no I generated these models with scaffold and it's basic

Comment: I'm using rails 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a typo in your `belongs_to`?  It should be `belongs_to :permission`

Also, use `permission_id` as your foreign key in the `account_group_permissions` table.